# wrong url to admin django after adding profile

Tags: django, admin, superuser

I had a login page that I would change it to another login page and I follow [these instructions](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html#sign-up-with-profile-model).

I added this code and when I tried to login to my user admin that I added before it sends me to wrong url http://localhost:8050/admin/login/?next=/admin/ and it throws :

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/login/

User has no profile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profile instance is generated on `post_save` signal, that is, you must save your `User` at least once after you added that `Profile` class.

The easiest workaround in your case would be to create a new admin user using `python manage.py createsuperuser`.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems like, You have a **`User`** in DB, but it doesn't have any `profile` relation ***now***.

**Solution:1**
Set `profile` instance for currently existing `User`'s in db through `django shell`.
1. log into django shell by `python manage.py shell`
2. run these commands,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myapp.models import Profile

for user in User.objects.all():
    Profile.objects.create(user=user)
```

3. then login to the django admin

**Solution:2**
Drop your database, (if you are using `sqlite`, the delete the corresponding file) and `migrate` and then create a new super user by **`python  manage.py createsuperuser`** command